# In Jmeter, I am not passing one value in request body but that value showing in response

Tags: api, jmeter, request, performance-testing, load-testing

1. In Jmeter, I am not passing one value in request body but that value showing in response. When I pass different value in script that time also any values not showing in response.if you are provide solutions that would be great.

PS: Application options are full of drop down boxes. In Default some values are selected

Answer (score 0):

Would be great if you show how did you "pass" the value and how exactly it's "showing" in the response.

JMeter doesn't know anything about drop-down boxes, it sends a HTTP request, waits for the response and measures the time in between.

You can use your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to see how various values in the drop-down boxes are reflected in the generated HTTP request parameters or record the requests(s) you need to simulate using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium).

The fact that the value is "showing" in response doesn't necessary mean that it's visible to the end user because it might be [hidden by CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp).